# Call private virtual functions from Base class object

Tags: c++, virtual, private

I have learned that it is better to keep virtual functions private, but in the code I posted below, unless the friendship can inherit, the function `call_inside()` should not be able to invoke the virtual function defined in D1 class. So I wonder how it works.

Thank you for your response.

```
#include<iostream>
struct B
{
friend void call_inside();
private:
  virtual void fun()  {std::cout<<"virtual_B"<<std::endl;}
};
struct D1:public B
{
private:
  void fun()override  {std::cout<<"virtual_D1"<<std::endl;}
};
void call_inside()
{
  B trial; D1 trial1;
  B *p=&trial, *p1=&trial1;
  p->fun();
  p1->fun();
}
int main()
{
  call_inside();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have one explanation myself: I invoke the private member of B inside it's friend function, thus it is totally legal at compile time. Which version of virtual function is invoked is determined at run time, when the private specifier of D1 does not matter.            I do not know whether it makes sense

Comment: If you want added head-scratching, remove the `friend` declaration, make `fun()` public in `B` only, and try `p1->fun()` and `trial1.fun()` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call_inside` function is a friend of `B`. Within `call_inside` you're invoking `fun` twice, both via pointers to instances of `B`. The fact that one of the `B` pointers actually points to a `D` is immaterial, because the type of the pointer used to invoke the function is `B`. If you instead call `trial1.fun()` in `call_inside`, you'll get a compilation error as expected due to `fun` being `private` on `D` and your attempt to call it through a `D` instance.

Comment: But in effect the private virtual function of D1 will be invoked by a non-friend function at run time. Could we say that private specifier does not matter at run time?

Comment: The runtime definitely does not do a type check in order to validate function access, if that's what you mean. Access specifiers are checked at compile time. The function is called on an instance of `B`, it's a function belonging to `B`, and in overriding it `D` has agreed to be part of the protocol of its invocation. Public inheritance means `D` *is-a* `B` in this context.

Comment: Thank you a lot. But although  `D` is public inherited from `B`, the private members of  `B`  should still be hidden from `D`. right?

Comment: Yes, but regarding `fun`, `D` is overriding a virtual function of its base `B`. Also, I don't have access to any recent C++ standards but the 1998 standard has this to say about access specifiers and virtual functions: "Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression used to denote the object for which the member function is called (`B*` in the example above). The access of the member function in the class in which it was defined (`D` in the example above) is in general not known." I'd guess that more recent standards still match these rules reasonably closely.